# How does python's dict .get() method check default argument?

Tags: python

I have met a strange Python behavior which is difficult to explain to myself. When I pass a default value for getting a key from a dict - looks like it firstly try to find that default value and next looks if key exists. And throws an error if the key exists in the dict. Why does that happen?

```
from collections import namedtuple
Test = namedtuple("TEST", "attr1 attr2 attr3")
obj_1 = Test("first", "second", "third")

obj_1.attr1
>>> 'first'
k_dict = {"red": "light", "green": "leaf"}    

k_dict.get("red")
>>> 'light'

k_dict.get("red", obj_1.attr4)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TEST' object has no attribute 'attr4'
```

**UPDATE:** I understand what is the problem here, but I can't understand why this is default behaviur of Python? Why not just check first part - if the `key` is in the dict and if not - check another part? Now it looks like not optimal way of computing that?

Comment: I'm confused. You do `obj_1.attr4` and there's no `attr4` on `obj_1`. What exactly you misunderstand here?

Comment: ```attr4```  isn't part of your namedtuple, it only goes up to ```attr3```

Comment: @freakish exatly this is what I am asking about - why does python checks if attribute exists before searching if the key is present in the dict?

Comment: It isn't the ```.get()``` it's because you are trying to use something ```attr4``` which doesn't exist. Jean's answer explains it better.

Comment: @Joshua Nixon I understand that, but I am not directly calling that value. By my mind that should be optionally called if the *key* is not present in the dict. But why Python checks it earlier? Why not not to check if key exists - next check if `attr4` exists?

Comment: Python checks the value as it passes it to the method. Python, or any other language, cannot pass something which doesn't exist to a method

Answer (score 5):

it has nothing to do with `dict.get`

When you call a function in python, arguments are evaluated.

In your case the key exists, but both arguments need to be evaluated before key lookup occurs.

For instance what would "work" would be:

```
k_dict.get("red") or obj_1.attr4
```

Since `red` key exists, the second argument isn't evaluated. It only crashes if `red` doesn't exist. It doesn't help much in that case (your way of doing it has the merit to catch the error whatever the outcome is at least so keep on doing it!), but if you had some complex computation to perform as the default argument it would:

```
k_dict.get("red",super_expensive_computation())
```

is slow even if `red` exists when:

```
k_dict.get("red") or super_expensive_computation()
```

is fast when `red` exists. The `or` technique relies on the fact that the values cannot be `0`, just `None`. Else just use `if "red" in k_dict` construct.